# Maven native dependences in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, lwjgl

I'm trying to get some native dependencies ([LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/)) working smoothly in Eclipse (Juno) with Maven.

Current situation:

- I'm using the `maven-nativedependencies-plugin` version 0.0.6. This seems to successfully download and unpack the native libraries to the `target/natives` subdirectory of my project. Fine so far.
- I can make the dependencies work by manually adding the `target/natives` directory in `Properties / Java Build Path / Maven Dependencies / Native Library Location / Edit...`
- However this only works temporarily as it doesn't seem that the native library location can be specified anywhere in the pom. In particular, it breaks whenever I do a `Maven / Update Project...` because the Native Library Location is cleared (presumably by m2e re-configuring the project according to the pom)
- Whenever the native library location is cleared, I just get the error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path"

What is the best way to get this working reliably?

Comment: Does this link help? It's a slightly hacky effort to get a non JAR resource onto the `java.library.path`: http://buildanddeploy.com/node/14

Comment: @Duncan - thanks! It's an interesting link though it's not an Eclipse example and I don't think it solves the core problem (i.e. blanking of the native library location in Eclipse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this steps;

- Go to the run configuration of your java project.
- Open the Arguments tab and enter "-Djava.library.path=target/natives"
  into the VM Arguments.

For maven project;

Make sure your pom.xml like this;

```
      <build>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3.2</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <source>1.5</source>
                                    <target>1.5</target>
                                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.googlecode.mavennatives</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-nativedependencies-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>0.0.6</version>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <id>unpacknatives</id>
                                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3.2</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <archive>
                                            <manifest>
                                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                                            </manifest>
                                    </archive>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2.1</version>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <id>bundle-project-sources</id>
                                            <phase>package</phase>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <descriptors>
                                                            <descriptor>src/META-INF/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                                                    </descriptors>
                                            </configuration>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

And then left click on the eclipse project, go to the maven menu and click on "update project configuration". If you are still having problems, in the eclipse console tab, open the maven console and do the "update project configuration" option again

Comment: Hmm.... this works on a one-off basis but doesn't help on the Maven side - e.g. the Native Library Location is still blank and Maven fails when running the test suite.

Comment: 10 month ago adding -Djava.library.path=path/to/dir was not needed, I reopened my project today, I had to change some of the maven-native-plugin configuration and add -Djava.library.path=path/to/dir to the VM argument, why?

Answer (score 4):

In my application, I need sqljdbc4.jar from MS. My project is a Maven project, so I had the same problem that I could not edit Native Library Location under sqljdbc4.jar in Eclipse.

My error is this:

> Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

So I added this:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Documents and Settings\ccrhlj01\My Documents\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86"
```

in my VM arguments.

- Go to the run configuration of your java project.
- Open the Arguments tab and enter `-Djava.library.path="C:\Documents and Settings\ccrhlj01\My Documents\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86"` into the VM Arguments.

Remember the quotation marks around the path. In my case, that is my location, you need to find your dll location.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can copy your dll to any directory on the PATH variable, ex: C:\Windows\System32. This way, you don't have to add the argument in the VM arguments tab in Eclipse.